# Error message "WebSocket HANDSHAKING - WebSocket REJECT - WebSocket DISCONNECT" in Django Channels

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, real-time, django-channels

I recently followed the official Django Channels documentation (version 4.0.0) to set up WebSockets in my Django project. I've gone through the [documentation tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) and configured my project correctly. However, when I attempt to test the service using [websocketking](https://websocketking.com), I'm encountering a handshaking issue.

Here are some details about my configuration:

1. My asgi.py file looks like this:

```
import os
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "schatai.settings")
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import schatai.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(schatai.routing.websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

2. My consumers.py file looks like this:

```
import json

from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class WsTestConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json["message"]

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_group_name, {"type": "chat_message", "message": message}
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event["message"]

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"message": message}))
```

3. My routing.py file looks like this:

```
from django.urls import re_path, path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$", consumers.SchataiConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path(r"ws/", consumers.WsTestConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

4. I've also configured my settings.py file in accordance with the documentation.

When I run the python manage.py runserver command, the server starts successfully on ASGI.

However, when I attempt to test my service using [websocketking](https://websocketking.com), I receive the following error message:

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/ [127.0.0.1:48198]
WebSocket REJECT /ws/ [127.0.0.1:48198]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/ [127.0.0.1:48198]
```

I'd like to know if anyone has encountered this issue before or if they have any ideas about what might be causing this handshaking problem. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score -1):

After encountering the handshaking problem with Django Channels and conducting thorough research, I've been able to resolve this issue. Here's the solution I found:

The error message "WebSocket HANDSHAKING" followed by "WebSocket REJECT" indicates that the WebSocket server couldn't accept the connection. This can be due to several reasons, but one common cause is incorrect configuration of allowed origins (AllowedHosts) in Django.

To resolve this issue, follow these steps:

1. Open your Django project's settings.py file.
2. Ensure that the ALLOWED_HOSTS variable is correctly configured to include the IP address or domain name you're using for your application. For example:

   ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost', 'websocketking.com']
3. Restart your Django server to apply the new changes.

It's ok. Here is the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/security.html) that helped me